# How to pass parameter to Jest spyon method

Tags: jestjs, react-typescript

I need to call redux selector method ResultSelector which accepts one input parameter and returns boolean If i dont have any input parameter it can be called like mentioned below. How can i pass input parameter to it.

```
test:
jest.spyOn(TestRedux, 'ResultSelector').mockReturnValue(true)

redux:
export const ResultSelector= (rootState: RootState) => (
  Id?: number
): access | undefined => {
  return employeeSelector(rootState).employee.find((e) => e.empId === Id)
    ?.access;
};
```

Comment: Please clarify the expected result you want to get.

Comment: Hi, I want the access flag(true/false) from the redux. In this case the ResultsSelector takes the Id as the input parameter. I want to know how can i pass the Id parameter from spyon method so that i get the desired flag value.

Comment: Why you are trying to mock `ResultSelector`? Why don't you just call the selector directly and pass the `id` parameter, like: `const selector = TestRedux.ResultSelector({});  selector(123);`.

Comment: This way i can call but i can return a specific value. for ex- like we do with .mockReturnValue(true)